Unit test while @JvmSuppressWildcards is used in repository binding
I am trying to unit test my viewModel which includes @JvmSuppressWildcards for repository :
@HiltViewModel
class BookmarkTVShowViewModel @Inject constructor(
    repository: @JvmSuppressWildcards BaseRepository<List<TVShow>>
) : BaseViewModel<List<TVShow>>(repository)

Here is my BaseViewModel :
open class BaseViewModel<T>(
    private val repository: BaseRepository<T>,
    private val id: Any? = null
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _stateFlow = MutableStateFlow<Resource<T>>(Resource.Loading)
    val stateFlow: StateFlow<Resource<T>>
        get() = _stateFlow

    fun refresh() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.getResult(id).collect {
                _stateFlow.tryEmit(it)
            }
        }
    }
}

And here is BaseRepository :
abstract class BaseRepository<T>(
    private val context: Context,
    private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
) {
    protected abstract suspend fun getSuccessResult(id: Any?): T

    fun getResult(id: Any?): Flow<Resource<T>> = flow {
        emit(Resource.Loading)
        try {
            emit(Resource.Success(getSuccessResult(id)))
        } catch (t: Throwable) {
            emit(Resource.Error(context.getString(R.string.failed_loading_msg)))
        }
    }.flowOn(ioDispatcher)
}

The test works as expected for viewModels without @JvmSuppressWildcards, such as :
@Test
    fun `load feeds`() {
        every { repository.getResult(any()) } returns flowOf(Resource.Loading)
        initViewModel()
        assertEquals(Resource.Loading, viewModel.stateFlow.value)
    }

@Test
    fun `load feeds success`() {
        every { repository.getResult(any()) } returns flowOf(Resource.Success(emptyList()))
        initViewModel()
        assertEquals(Resource.Success(emptyList<FeedWrapper>()), viewModel.stateFlow.value)
    } 

But for my BookmarkTVShowViewModel, it always return Resource.Loading, and it seems Resource.Success is not mocked. Do you guys know why?
Here is how my repository is binding :
    @Singleton
    @Binds
    @JvmSuppressWildcards
    internal abstract fun bindBookmarkTVShowRepository(bookmarkTVShowRepository: BookmarkTVShowRepository): BaseRepository<List<TVShow>>

And here is actual implementation of Repository :
@Singleton
class BookmarkTVShowRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val tvShowDao: TVShowDao,
    @ApplicationContext context: Context,
    @IoDispatcher ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher,
) : BaseRepository<List<@JvmSuppressWildcards TVShow>>(context, ioDispatcher) {

    override suspend fun getSuccessResult(id: Any?): List<TVShow> =
        tvShowDao.getBookmarks().asDomainModel()
}

Source code can be found here : https://github.com/alirezaeiii/TMDb-Compose-Playground/tree/main
